# MvvmCross SQLite.Net-PCL plugin missing assembly

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

So i've added the "MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.SQLitePCL" version "4.0.0-beta6" to my solution (My core, my android and my iphone projects).

I can now use SQLite.Net, and i can build for android and iPhoneSimulator. However, as soon as I switch to "iPhone" as my target, I get the following error:

```
Failed to resolve assembly: 'SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinIOS, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' SimplyRemember.Touch
```

It makes sense that it cannot find this assembly, as it is indeed not listed under "References" - Only the "SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinIOS.Unified" is. Notice the ".Unified".

I have tried cleaning my solution. I have tried wiping my "/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs" folder. I have tried wiping my "packages" folder in my solution, and restoring all packages. Same result every time.

As a sidenote, this was also the case when i used SQLitePCL version "4.0.0-beta5" in which i had added its dependencies to SQLite.Net-PCL 3.0.5 and SQLite.Net.Async-PCL 3.0.5 manually

Full packages.config for my Touch project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Acr.Support" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="xamarinios1" />
  <package id="Acr.UserDialogs" version="4.1.8" targetFramework="xamarinios1" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Binding" version="4.0.0-beta5" targetFramework="xamarinios1" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore" version="4.0.0-beta5" targetFramework="xamarinios1" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries" version="4.0.0-beta5" targetFramework="xamarinios1" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.SQLitePCL" version="4.0.0-beta6" targetFramework="xamarinios1" />
  <package id="MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack" version="4.0.0-beta5" targetFramework="xamarinios1" />
  <package id="Splat" version="1.6.2" targetFramework="xamarinios1" />
  <package id="SQLite.Net.Async-PCL" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="xamarinios1" />
  <package id="SQLite.Net-PCL" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="xamarinios1" />
  <package id="StyleCop.Analyzers" version="1.0.0-beta014" targetFramework="xamarinios1" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>
```

Comment: It's being worked on: https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/issues/234

Comment: It is 4.0.0-beta8 and the issue is still not resolved.

Where you able to find any workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. I've worked around it by using an older version of SQLite.Net